# call html onclick from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code structure like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function something()
{
  alert("insomething");
}
</script>

<input type="text" onclick="check" id="clk"/>

----------
```

I wanted to know how can i trigger clk.click () ? from a jquery below:

```
$('.btn.right').click(function(e) {
     $("#clk").onclick(); //DOES NOT WORK.. Need help with this.
}
```

Comment: If you want your syntax, use `$('#clk').trigger('click');` instead of `$('#clk').onclick();`.

Comment: Why did you include your `function something()` code? Nothing calls it.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock please explain the difference. `trigger()` vs `click()`

Comment: take a look at this [webpage](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp). From now on, your bible.

Comment: @BrOSs - w3schools.com should never be considered the bible for any code.

Comment: @Nick I don't believe `.onclick()` is a jQuery function, so it would not work with a jQuery object.

Comment: @Nick To my understanding, `.trigger` uses extra parameters. the extraParameters argument to .trigger() allows information to be determined at the time the event is triggered, while the alternative argument requires the information to be already computed at the time the handler is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you can trigger the exact same response as if the user had clicked something by doing the following:

`$("#clk").click();`

Comment: it works but when i wish to pass parameters to it.. so $("#clk").click('yes'); //it fails.. I did change the function signature to take in 1 parameter..

Comment: @user2547591 Why are you doing this in this way? It seems extremely... wrong somehow.

Comment: well its kind of a long code and i dont want to paste all junk in here nor do i want to merge the two codes.. hence the question.

Comment: @user2547591 Okay, but this is not the correct way to do this. Having functions on the `onclick` that you want to pass arguments to is just wrong, because they will be triggered by the standard click all the time with no arguments.

Comment: okay, so how can i manage parameter passing too. what if the click function takes in one parameter.. ie function check(val1) { alert(val1); }

Comment: Else to rephrase how can i call the js code for the onclick ie CHECK via jquery :(

Comment: It would help a lot if you give us some background info about what you are doing -- just a sentence or two. I don't think any of us can understand how/why a click function could use a parameter..?

Comment: @user2547591 Click functions are just that. They happen when clicked. **No parameters are meant to be passed into click functions.** There is absolutely no reason why you would do this.

Comment: @user2547591 Here what is? I don't see any changes. Also, in your original question, the two code samples don't appear to be related in any way. Help us to understand how they go together. What will the click function do with the YES parameter when it gets it?  What OTHER paramater could a click function possibly receive?

Comment: ok here it is. there is a navigation button that collapses the current div and shows the next question in expanded form. --THIS IS HANDLED BY JQUERY CODE U CAN SEE.                  Now right next to the question there is a placeholder for a answer textbox. If user clicks that check() javascript method is called. this method checks if the user entered Boolean yes or no.. or if he entered a integer type say 0-9 and so on... its needed for some processing......     So.. if the user entered a value in the answer and clicks next button i want the nextbutton to even trigger check() method.

Comment: QUESTION  | [ANSWER TEXTBOX : Check()]                                 >> (jqeury :btn.right)

Comment: @user2547591 What you just wrote is gibbrish for anyone that has no idea what you are trying to do (still), especially when you say  things like "it is needed for some processing". This is not the proper way to do what you describe, anyway. Click methods **are meant to process CLICKS by the user clicking on something on the page**!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `click()` method documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
$('.btn.right').click(function(e) {
     $("#clk").click(); 
}
```

With no parameters, it's shortcut for `.trigger('click')`.

Comment: it works but when i wish to pass parameters to it.. so  $("#clk").click('yes'); //it fails.. I did change the function signature to take in 1 parameter..

Comment: What do you mean click yes? It's just a _click_.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the comments, I decided to write an answer.

I feel you may be slightly confused with how functions work.  You cannot simply pass a parameter through a `click` event (it is an event/action), not to mention the inline onclick function does not accept parameters. In your current example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function something()
{
  alert("insomething");
}
</script>

<input type="text" onclick="check" id="clk"/>
```

You are referencing `function check` when the click event occurs. However, `check` does not not exist. If you wanted to pass a parameter to `function something`, you would need to write it like this:

`<input type="text" onclick="something(*parameter*)" id="clk"/>`

However, you would then need to edit `function something()` so it takes parameters. So you would change it to `function something(param)`.

If you wanted to pass a parameter through a click event, then you would need to use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).  However, you would then need to change up your code a bit.

Try doing something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="clk"/>

<button class="btn right">Click</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    function something(a) //a is the parameter
    {
      alert(a);
    }

    $('#clk').click(function(e, parm1, parm2){
        //parm1 is first object in extraparameters array, parm2 is second
        something(parm1);
        something(parm2);
    });

    $('.btn.right').click(function(e) {
        $("#clk").trigger('click', ['something', 'somethingelse'] );
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Z3YWb/1/

Hope this helps!